# How do I get back into my developer account?

Tags: login

I am locked out of my developer account. I am the only person at my company that uses Salesforce, so there is no admin that I can turn to for help. I have clicked the "Did you forget your password?" link about a dozen times, but I never get an email from Salesforce (and yes, I've checked the spam folder, many times).

I looked here:

```
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000005251&language=en_US&type=1
```

The page says:

*If you're the only Administrator and you can't access your login, create a case with Salesforce Customer Support and request to reset your password (please include your username in your case details).*

It offers a link, but when I click on the link, it asks me to log in!!!! That is frustrating. The link to help me login needs me to login!!!

Anyway, how can I get back into Salesforce?

This is just a developer account, my company has never paid any money to Salesforce, so we don't have any kind of support contract with Salesforce.

(My company does not use Salesforce, but we developed a plugin for the Salesforce App Exchange.)

Comment: Hmm... Create another developer account. That's most viable option apparently with your org state. :-)

Comment: On second thought, I believe, if the user is locked then after some time you can generate the Password reset request. But not at this moment. I believe I am recalling this information correctly.

Comment: This is crazy. There is no easy way for me to recover the work done with the first account? Our account in the App Exchange is linked to that first account.